# Rsyslog with nas

Tags: sys, rsyslog, nas

Sure, here is an explanation of your problem:

My rsyslog configuration is not working. I am trying to use it to log messages from the system, but it is not capturing any of the messages. I have checked the configuration file and it seems to be set up correctly, but I am not sure what the issue could be. Any help or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Template
#template ( name="LongTagForwardFormat"
#           type="string"
#          string="<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%$.suffix%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg%")

# Ruleset
ruleset(name="nas") {

    if ($fromhost-ip == 'x.x.x.x) then /test/syslog/admin/nas/nasperge.log
    & stop;

    if ($fromhost-ip == 'x.x.x.x') then /test/syslog/admin/nas/nastronote.log
    & stop;

# Règle "else" qui envoie tous les autres journaux vers le fichier purestorage.log
    if ($fromhost-ip != 'x.x.x.x' && $fromhost-ip != 'x.x.x.x') then /X.X.X.X/syslog/admin/nas/purestorage.log
    & stop;


#action(
#   type="omfile"
#   file="/test/syslog/admin/cloud/esx.log"
#)

#   if ($msg contains "verbose" || $syslogseverity-text == "info"
#       ) then {
#       stop
#   }
#   /test/syslog/admin/nas/nas.log
}

# Input`your text`
input(type="imudp"
    address="X.X.X.X"
    port="514"
    ruleset="nas"
)

#action(type="omfile" file="/test/syslog/server/web_farm/oscar-price.log")
```

Comment: What format are you using to send the logs (config on the NAS)?

Comment: I don't know if these are just copy-paste errors or if this your original file, but e.g. on line 9 you're missing a single-quote and I can't see where you've loaded the `imudp` module - `module(load="imudp")`. Run `rsyslogd -N1` to check your config validity.